# Craft CMS 5: Can I query entries and matrix-fields together?

Tags: matrix, craft5

If matrix fields become entries in Craft 5, is the following scenario possible, robust and efficient?

- Channel  "speakers"
- Channel  "solo events":
  with an entryfield for selecting a speaker
- Channel "conferences"
  A conference will have different events and I want to store them in a matrix field, each "conference-sub-event" have an entryfield for selecting a speaker

Can I load all speakers from "solo events" and from the matrix field of the "conference-sub-events" in a query and generate a list with all speakers from all solo events and all conference-sub-events?